# Dictionary sort automatically in for loop Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have write down this program in python

Create a dictionary

```
 a = { 'a':'b', 'x':'x', '2':'2' }
```

After run loop

```
 for c in a:
   a[c]
```

result is

```
'2'
'b'
'x'
```

I expect, there should be "b x 2" result but it sort automatically, Why happen this and how can i control this?

Answer (score 1):

**Dictionary** in python is not ordered , the order in which you are receiving the keys is basically dependent on the python implementation. Your code should not depend on it.

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) -

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an **unordered set of key: value pairs**, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)

---

If order is important for your program, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) . Example -

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict([('a','b'),('x','x'),('2','2')])
>>> for c in d:
...     d[c]
...
'b'
'x'
'2'
```

Comment: if i want this result b x 2 then what i need to implement ?

Comment: Use `collections.OrderedDict` , gave an example in the answer.